# Chrome below the normal size

Tags: 13.04, google-chrome, fonts

I've been an Ubuntu user for a while and this is the first time I have such a problem. It is quite difficult to explain so I attach [a screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IS0qi.png):

[image: screenshot].

Basically the font size is too small. In the screenshot I've attached how I see Chrome at 100% zoom, as you see it is like if it was not taking the whole space at disposal. Even the terminal, the buttons on top of the windows looks smaller.

Is it a choice of Ubuntu 13.04? Did I by mistake touch something wrong?

Comment: @LuigiTiburzi: Simple your `Screen Resolution` is too high! Try to change it from `System Settings` -> `Displays`

Comment: This is the default font size for Google Chrome.

Comment: But why if I have a certain resolution I'm forced to lower it??? Can't I have a decent view in another way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chrome menu > Settings > Advanced > Web Content, and you can change the font size.

You can also use the zoom feature, though this will change the size of everything, text and images.  Either hold control and use the scroll wheel to change the zoom, or you can change it from the Chrome menu's top directory.

Comment: I tried the zoom before but the problem is not only with chrome, with the whole OS. Everything is smaller due the 'too high screen resolution' and I'd like a way to zoom everything, not just Chrome. Is that possible?

Comment: you asked about Chrome, I gave you an answer about chrome!  If that wasn't what you were looking for, then this is a bad question.  If you want everything zoomed in, then maybe just lower your resolution.  That's the point of a lower resolution...  If you just want all your fonts to be larger, try setting the DPI to a different setting.  If you just want your icons to be larger, set them larger in the appropriate setting.  If you want just icons AND fonts to be larger, do both.  Otherwise, you'll have to ask a clearer question.  Good luck!